# EAR switching in the application

Tags: ear

we are having a scenario like this where we want to have different releases of our project.
 We call it as R1.0 and R2.0.
 First we are releasing R1.1 to all 5 plants. R2.0 will be released first to 2 plants and then remaining 3 plants.
 It is possible that some users will have access to both the plants and some may not.
 The requirement is that once a user having multiple plant access logs in he should be directed to plant having higher version let say  R2.0 and from there he will have an option to switch back to another plant having lower version say R1.0.

To handle this scenario we have come up with the following approach.
 we will have 2 EARs one for R1.0 and another one for  R2.0.
 The requests will always come to the EAR 2.0 if that is released.
 We will maintain a filter class which will check in DB if the user is having access to multiple plants. if no and the plant to which he has access is R1.0 then simply redirect to EAR 1.0 , otherwise he will be in EAR 2.0 only.

Also once he is accessing EAR 2.0 screens there will be a drop down in 2 screens from where he can switch to plant having lower version . so from there also we need to redirect him to EAR 1.0.

We are planning for a simple sendredirect with required parameters to the another EAR file.
Please let us know what should be the correct approach, or the approach we have taken is correct.

Comment: We are using Websphere application server and our technical stack is struts2, spring, hibernate.